# По нажатию кнопки выполнить два действия

Tags: php

Как нажатием одной кнопки отправить данные и на сайт и в sql ?

```
<form action="laravel.php" method="post" id="nameform" >

     <?php

     $data='room1';

    echo  '<button type="submit" name="mysel" form="nameform" value='.$data.'>Отправить</button>';

    $conn=getDentrix();

    $sql = "exec = dbo.TEST '$data', 1";
    $params = array( array(&$fun, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_INT) );


    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
    if( $stmt === false )
    {
      echo "Error in executing query.";
      die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    ?>

      </form>
```

Comment: Для начала надо прочесть вот это: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke

Comment: @Bloom почему у Вас php прям внутри формы? это должно быть в файле laravel.php. И что делает процедура dbo.TEST?

Comment: exec может как принимать данные так и выводить, в данном случаи на кнопку Отправить вешается два действия, чтоб в laravel php когда перейдёт то там будет свой запрос sql , но этот запрос уже будет знать что нажата кнопка с данными и лишнего функция запроса не отдаст